# Recursion function called terdragon in Code Maven is ununderstandable

Tags: javascript

```
   var n = 8;
   var l = 5;
   var angle = 120 * Math.PI / 180;

   c.translate(300, 200);
   terdragon(n);

   function terdragon(n) {
     if (n <= 1) {
       drawLine(l);
     } else {
       terdragon(n-1);
       c.rotate(angle);
       terdragon(n-1);
       c.rotate(-angle);
       terdragon(n-1);
     }
   }
   function drawLine(l) {
     c.beginPath();
     c.moveTo(0, 0);
     c.lineTo(l, 0);
     c.stroke();
     // Finish at the end of the line we drew
     c.translate(l, 0);
   }
```

I don't understand how does it draw the lines as it does, when variable n is 8. As it is stated that if n <= 1 then call the drawLine function, until then it does nothing but calls itself and subtracts 1 each time and changes angle, but I can't see how does it draw, when it doesn't equal to 1.

The code is from Crunchzilla Code Maven. Chapter 40 - Fractals

Comment: It is certainly unusual, at first glance, but the key thing is that it calls itself and subtracts 1  not "each time" as you state, but THREE times. So, when n=3 for example, then drawLine(l) occurs twice.

Comment: I don't see how is that possible, since the drawLine function within the terdragon recursion is applied only when n<=1, so in the else section there is no way it would draw anything, until the if statement becomes true. What am I missing?

Comment: My mistake - I thought that  n  was being updated each pass, but not in that section of code! What does c.rotate() do - are there any side-effects?

Comment: c.rotate - from the CANVAS API rotates the object or shape created by predefined bulit-in functions by the defined radians(can be converted into degrees).